# How to convert Date in angular to another time zone

Tags: angular, angular-date-format

I am using `Date()` to get the current time in local time zone. And I have formatted that as follows:

```
this.today = new Date();
      from = new DatePipe('en-Us').transform(this.today, 'dd:MM:yyyy hh-mm-ss');
```

Now I want to convert the `from` date time to `Europe/London` time zone.
How Can I do this without `moment`.
Please help me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved my issue by adding an another parameter for timezone according to https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Here is the update code:

```
to = new DatePipe('en-Us').transform(this.today, 'dd:MM:yyyy hh-mm-ss', 'GMT+1');
```

Comment: Yes, that is the answer,

Comment: I don't think this supports `Europe/London` or something similar. Is there a way to avoid providing the offset?

Comment: Caveat: If you give the input date as a string but without a timezone portion, the string will be parsed under the assumption of belonging to the timezone given as third parameter.

Comment: @Anil sir can  you tell me how to pass America/Los_Angeles in above function?

Comment: I'm thinking we could use an static dictionary with whatever key you want and then the offset as a value. 

{ pst: -0700 } // vegas